# Nextjs component not updating after state change

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, next.js, render

I have an array of products for which I'm using context api to maintain their state and cookies to persist them after refresh. On a click event I want to increase the number of items loaded from the context and store them as updated cookies. The data itself is updated and saved but the UI is not showing its change until a refresh.

```
const context = useContext(AppContext)

const [cartContext, setCartContext] = useState([]);
const [currentImage, setCurrentImage] = useState()
const [currentQuantity, setCurrentQuantity] = useState(false)
const [cartCookie, setCartCookie] = useState([]);

useEffect(()=>{
    if(currentImage != undefined) {
        context.cart[currentImage].quantity += 1
        Cookie.set("cartCookie", JSON.stringify(cartCookie));
    }
}, [currentQuantity])

useEffect(() => {
    setCartCookie(context.cart)
}, [context.cart]);

function findImg(img) {
const findImg = cartContext.findIndex((item, index) => item.name == img.name)
    return findImg
} 

useEffect(() => {
  setCartContext(context.cart)
}, [context.cart, cartContext])

return(
  {cartContext.map((image) => (        
      <div>       
        <Row>
            <Col>
                   <img src={image.img} alt="" />
                <div>
                    <p>
                      <strong>{image.category}</strong> <br/> {image.name}
                    </p>
                </div>
            </Col>
            <Col>
                <div className={styles.cartColBox}>
                  {image.price}
                </div>
            </Col>
            <Col> 
                <div>
                    <div className={styles.cartMiddleBox}>
                        {image.quantity}
                    </div>
                        <div>
                            <div  onClick={() =>
                            (setCurrentImage(findImg(image)), setCurrentQuantity(!currentQuantity))
                            }>
                                +
                            </div>
                            <div>
                                -
                            </div>
                        </div>
            
                    </div>
                </Col>
                <Col>
                    <div>
                    100
                    </div>
                </Col>
            </Row>    
            </div> 
    ))}  
   )
```

Comment: Why do you do shenanigans with useEffect ? You can do ```onClick={()=>{ImageStuff();setCurrentQuantity(qty => qty+1)}}```

Comment: I don't see why would that work.

Comment: i dont think your on click function is written correctly. try the code in the first comment

Comment: setCurrentQuantity is a boolean beacuse that's how the app switches between images.

Comment: Try this `setCurrentQuantity(currentQuantity => !currentQuantity)`

Comment: Sadly it has the same effect.

Answer (score 2):

I had to use spread operators for the array states. The issue was that by default JavaScript doesn't recognize the change if a value changes within the array. Also explained here: https://github.com/vercel/next.js/discussions/32802